# Como usar plugins no Cordova

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova

Olá! Estou acabando um app com Cordova, mas reparei em 2 coisas q estavam faltando que seria transição de páginas mais suave igual nativo e som ao clicar em um link.

Os 2 plugins já estão instalados, mas como estou aprendendo agora com javascript não sei como chamar eles. Minha pergunta é como faço pra fazer essa chamada? Já li as instruções mas não entendi a explicação.

Encontrei esses 2 plugins:

Transição de Páginas: https://www.npmjs.com/package/com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions

Som ao Clicar:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativeclicksound

Comment: Qual compilador está usando? (Phonegap, Adobe PhoneGap Build, etc).

Comment: Olá! Instalei o Java, node e cordova e estou compilando pelo executar.

Comment: Quando você diz "fazer essa chamada" se refere a executar os plugins em uma página ou "linkar" ela na página assim como fazemos com css e javascript através das tags link e script?

Comment: Então, no XML ficou assim:
<plugin name="com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions" spec="^0.6.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativeclicksound" spec="0.0.3" />

E pelo que vi na documentação, tem que chamar os scripts. E isso não tô sabendo fazer.

Comment: Já experimentou compilar diretamente? Quando eu usava o IntelXDK não precisava linkar, ele adicionava os plugins em tempo de compilação